Coordinates of vertices in 3D
I have 10 vertices that are part of a set of 8 triangles. Initially they are:
points = {{0.0, 0.0, 0}, {-1.0, 0.0, 0}, {-0.5, -0.866025, 
0}, {-0.4999999999999999, 0.8660249999999999, 
0}, {-1.499999650312418, 0.8660252018922197, 
0}, {0.49999965031241855, 0.8660247981077804, 
0}, {-1.9999996503122555, 0, 0}, {0.0007240701365166524, 
1.7316315539325131, 0}, {1.0007233705929623, 1.7307950662639358, 
0}, {1.4999989514443854, 0.8643522262620842, 0}};

So they are on a 2D plane. Now I define my triangles:
trik1 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Polygon[{points[[1]], points[[2]], points[[3]]}]}; (*4*)
trik2 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Polygon[{points[[2]], points[[1]], points[[4]]}]};(*3*)
trik3 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Polygon[{points[[2]], points[[4]], points[[5]]}]};(*2*)
trik4 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Polygon[{points[[4]], points[[1]], points[[6]]}]};(*5*)
trik5 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Polygon[{points[[2]], points[[5]], points[[7]]}]}; (*1*)
trik6 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Polygon[{points[[4]], points[[6]], points[[8]]}]};(*8*)
trik7 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Polygon[{points[[8]], points[[6]], points[[9]]}]};(*6*)
trik8 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Polygon[{points[[9]], points[[6]], points[[10]]}]};(*7*)

I now define 7 different angles and create a manipulate enviroment so I can use sliders to create different 3D structures:
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Rotate[{Rotate[{Rotate[trik5, -ang1, 
        points[[2]] - points[[5]], points[[5]]], trik3}, ang2, 
      points[[4]] - points[[2]], points[[2]]], 
     Rotate[trik1, -ang3, points[[1]] - points[[2]], points[[2]]], 
     trik2}, -1 ang4, points[[1]] - points[[4]], points[[4]]], trik4, 
   Rotate[{trik6, 
     Rotate[{trik7, 
       Rotate[trik8, -ang5, points[[9]] - points[[6]], points[[6]]]}, 
      ang6, points[[6]] - points[[8]], points[[8]]]}, -ang7, 
    points[[4]] - points[[6]], points[[6]]]}], {{ang1, 0, 
   "rotate ang1"}, -Pi, Pi}, {{ang2, 0, "rotate ang2"}, -Pi, Pi}, {{ang3, 0, "rotate ang3"}, -Pi, Pi}, 
{{ang4, 0, "rotate ang4"}, -Pi, Pi}, {{ang5, 0, "rotate ang5"}, -Pi, Pi}, 
{{ang6, 0, "rotate ang6"}, -Pi, Pi}, {{ang7, 0, "rotate ang7"}, -Pi, Pi}]

I'm going to need the coordinates of the vertices for different 3D structures with different angles. Is there a way for me to obtain these vertices easily with Mathematica, knowing that I have the angles of rotation?

Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory Tour now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by clicking the gray triangles, because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by clicking the checkmark sign! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

The trick is to know the axis you are rotating around, then this should be fairly straightforward. Just look in the documentation for Rotation Transformations

Perhaps RotationTransform[] could be used.

To shorten the code, use indexed variables, e.g., trik[1] vice trik1. Then, Evaluate[trik /@ Range[8]] = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], Polygon[#]} & /@ Map[points[[#]] &, {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 1, 4}, {2, 4, 5}, {4, 1, 6}, {2, 5, 7}, {4, 6, 8}, {8, 6, 9}, {9, 6, 10}}, {2}]; The Manipulate controls are similarly replaced with Evaluate[Sequence @@ ({{ang[#], 0, StringForm["rotate ``", Subscript[Style["\[MeasuredAngle]", 14], #]]}, -3.14, 3.14, 0.01, Appearance -> "Labeled"} & /@ Range[7])]

You can get the coordinates of the vertices by successive rotations of the original vertices:
points = {{0.0, 0.0, 0}, {-1.0, 0.0, 0}, {-0.5, -0.866025, 
    0}, {-0.4999999999999999, 0.8660249999999999, 
    0}, {-1.499999650312418, 0.8660252018922197, 
    0}, {0.49999965031241855, 0.8660247981077804, 
    0}, {-1.9999996503122555, 0, 0}, {0.0007240701365166524, 
    1.7316315539325131, 0}, {1.0007233705929623, 1.7307950662639358, 
    0}, {1.4999989514443854, 0.8643522262620842, 0}};

trik1 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 
   Polygon[{points[[1]], points[[2]], points[[3]]}]}; (*4*)
trik2 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 
   Polygon[{points[[2]], points[[1]], points[[4]]}]};(*3*)
trik3 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 
   Polygon[{points[[2]], points[[4]], points[[5]]}]};(*2*)
trik4 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 
   Polygon[{points[[4]], points[[1]], points[[6]]}]};(*5*)
trik5 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 
   Polygon[{points[[2]], points[[5]], points[[7]]}]}; (*1*)
trik6 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 
   Polygon[{points[[4]], points[[6]], points[[8]]}]};(*8*)
trik7 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 
   Polygon[{points[[8]], points[[6]], points[[9]]}]};(*6*)
trik8 = {RGBColor[1, 1, 1], 
   Polygon[{points[[9]], points[[6]], points[[10]]}]};(*7*)

lab[pts_] := Table[Text[i, pts[[i]], {1, 1}], {i, 10}];
tri[pts_] := Triangle[{{pts[[1]], pts[[2]], pts[[3]]}, 
    {pts[[2]], pts[[1]], pts[[4]]},
    {pts[[2]], pts[[4]], pts[[5]]},
    {pts[[4]], pts[[1]], pts[[6]]},
    {pts[[2]], pts[[5]], pts[[7]]},
    {pts[[4]], pts[[6]], pts[[8]]},
    {pts[[8]], pts[[6]], pts[[9]]},
    {pts[[9]], pts[[6]], pts[[10]]}}];
getpts[points_, a1_, a2_, a3_, a4_, a5_, a6_, a7_] := 
 Module[{pts = points, rot},
  rot[p0_, the_, p1_, p2_] := 
   RotationMatrix[the, p2 - p1] . (p0 - p1) + p1;
  pts[[{2, 3, 5, 7}]] = 
   rot[#, a4, pts[[1]], points[[4]]] & /@ pts[[{2, 3, 5, 7}]];
  pts[[{5, 7}]] = rot[#, a2, pts[[1]], points[[4]]] & /@ pts[[{5, 7}]];
  pts[[{7}]] = rot[#, a1, pts[[1]], points[[4]]] & /@ pts[[{7}]];
  pts[[{3}]] = rot[#, a3, pts[[1]], points[[4]]] & /@ pts[[{3}]];
  
  pts[[{8, 9, 10}]] = 
   rot[#, a7, pts[[4]], points[[6]]] & /@ pts[[{8, 9, 10}]];
  pts[[{9, 10}]] = 
   rot[#, a6, pts[[8]], points[[6]]] & /@ pts[[{9, 10}]];
  pts[[{10}]] = rot[#, a5, pts[[9]], points[[6]]] & /@ pts[[{10}]];
  
  pts
  ]


Manipulate[{
  
  pts = getpts[points, ang1, ang2, ang3, ang4, ang5, ang6, ang7];
  NumberForm[
   Grid[Prepend[pts // Chop, {"x", "Y", "Z"}], Frame -> All, 
    ItemSize -> 4], 2],
  Graphics3D[{Rotate[{Rotate[{Rotate[trik5, -ang1, 
         points[[2]] - points[[5]], points[[5]]], trik3}, ang2, 
       points[[4]] - points[[2]], points[[2]]], 
      Rotate[trik1, -ang3, points[[1]] - points[[2]], points[[2]]], 
      trik2}, -1 ang4, points[[1]] - points[[4]], points[[4]]], trik4,
     Rotate[{trik6, 
      Rotate[{trik7, 
        Rotate[trik8, -ang5, points[[9]] - points[[6]], points[[6]]]},
        ang6, points[[6]] - points[[8]], points[[8]]]}, -ang7, 
     points[[4]] - points[[6]], points[[6]]], 
    Evaluate@lab[pts]}]}, {{ang1, 0, "rotate ang1"}, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {{ang2, 0, "rotate ang2"}, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {{ang3, 0, "rotate ang3"}, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {{ang4, 0, "rotate ang4"}, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {{ang5, 0, "rotate ang5"}, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {{ang6, 0, "rotate ang6"}, -Pi, 
  Pi}, {{ang7, 0, "rotate ang7"}, -Pi, Pi}]



Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed.
